# No se visualiza jTable con java Swing!

Tags: java, json, java-swing, jtable, jsonobject

quería preguntarles si saben por que no se muestra mi JTable y sale un cuadro desfasado, lo que pasa es que la información la extraigo desde un archivo.json a la tabla, pero al hacer todo el procedimiento no se muestra, es este mi código:
Nota: 
Ya lo tenía declarado al principio de mi clase es este:

```
JScrollPane miBarra = new JScrollPane(miTabla1);



private void jbInit() throws Exception {
        this.setSize(new Dimension(500, 400));
        jProgreso.setOrientation(JProgressBar.HORIZONTAL);
        jProgreso.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        jProgreso.setVisible(false);
        jProgreso.setEnabled(true);
        jProgreso.setDoubleBuffered(false);
        jProgreso.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100, 25));
        jProgreso.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100, 25));
        jProgreso.setOpaque(false);
        jProgreso.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 25));
        jProgreso.setString("0%");
        jProgreso.setStringPainted(true);
        jProgreso.setBounds(new Rectangle(55, 318, 397, 33));
        jLabelFileName.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 0, 14));

        jTAExplicacion.setBounds(new Rectangle(30, 30, 408, 82));
        jTAExplicacion.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder());
        jTAExplicacion.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
        jTAExplicacion.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
        jTAExplicacion.setOpaque(false);
        jTAExplicacion.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
        jTAExplicacion.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
        jTAExplicacion.setEditable(false);
        jTAExplicacion.setLineWrap(true);
        jTAExplicacion.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        jTAExplicacion.setText(EXPLICACION_PREVIA_A_IMP);
        jTAExplicacion.setRows(5);
        jTAExplicacion.setFocusable(false);
        jTAExplicacion.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));

        jTAMensajes.setBounds(new Rectangle(10, 235, 450, 68));
        jTAMensajes.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder());
        jTAMensajes.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
        jTAMensajes.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
        jTAMensajes.setOpaque(false);
        jTAMensajes.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
        jTAMensajes.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
        jTAMensajes.setVisible(false);
        jTAMensajes.setEditable(false);
        jTAMensajes.setLineWrap(true);
        jTAMensajes.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        jTAMensajes.setText("Preparando la importacion");
        jTAMensajes.setRows(3);
        jTAMensajes.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));

        jLabelFileName.setBounds(new Rectangle(31, 134, 200, 20));
        jLabelFileName.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(80, 20));
        jLabelFileName.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(80, 20));
        jLabelFileName.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 20));
        jLabelFileName.setToolTipText("Indique el nombre del archivo a importar");
        jLabelFileName.setText("Archivo a importar:");
        jTextFieldFilename.setBounds(new Rectangle(32, 160, 325, 20));
        jTextFieldFilename.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200, 20));
        jTextFieldFilename.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 20));
        jTextFieldFilename.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 20));
        jTextFieldFilename.setText("Nombre del Archivo a importar");
        jButtonContinuar.setBounds(new Rectangle(119, 198, 100, 20));
        jButtonContinuar.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(73, 25));
        jButtonContinuar.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(81, 25));
        jButtonContinuar.setToolTipText(
            "Presione para continuar con la importacion de archivos");
        jButtonContinuar.setActionCommand("jButtonContinuarAction");
        jButtonContinuar.setMnemonic('C');
        jButtonContinuar.setText("Continuar");
        jButtonCancelar.setMnemonic('X');
        jButtonCancelar.setText("Cancelar");
        jButtonCancelar.setBounds(new Rectangle(265, 198, 100, 25));
        jButtonCancelar.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(73, 25));
        jButtonCancelar.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(81, 25));
        jButtonCancelar.setToolTipText(
            "Presione para salir de esta pantalla");

        jButtonAbortar.setMnemonic('X');
        jButtonAbortar.setText("Cancelar");
        jButtonAbortar.setBounds(new Rectangle(200, 200, 100, 25));
        jButtonAbortar.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(73, 25));
        jButtonAbortar.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(81, 25));
        jButtonAbortar.setToolTipText(
            "Presione para cancelar la importacion de archivos");
        jButtonAbortar.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));

        jButtonFileChooser.setMnemonic('S');
        jButtonFileChooser.setText("Seleccionar");
        jButtonFileChooser.setBounds(new Rectangle(368, 160, 100, 25));
        jButtonFileChooser.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(73, 25));
        jButtonFileChooser.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(81, 25));
        jButtonFileChooser.setToolTipText("Presione para seleccionar el archivo");

        jButtonFileChooser.addActionListener(new FileChooserActionListener());
        jButtonCancelar.addActionListener(new CancelListener());
        jButtonAbortar.addActionListener(new CancelListener());
        jButtonContinuar.addActionListener(new ProcesaImportacionListener());
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        this.getContentPane().add(jTAExplicacion);
        this.getContentPane().add(jProgreso, null);
        this.getContentPane().add(jTAMensajes, null);
        this.getContentPane().add(jLabelFileName, null);
        this.getContentPane().add(jTextFieldFilename, null);
        this.getContentPane().add(jButtonFileChooser, null);
        this.getContentPane().add(jButtonCancelar, null);
        this.getContentPane().add(jButtonAbortar, null);
        this.getContentPane().add(jButtonContinuar, null);

        jProgreso.setVisible(false);
        jButtonAbortar.setVisible(false);

        add(miBarra);
        miBarra.setBounds(27, 72, 379, 130);



    }

    private void construirTabla(){
        setTitle("Json Importados");
        String data [][]={};    
        String col[]={"TIPO EVENTO SIC","TIPO DERECHO COVACK",
                        "ES_REGIMEN_FISCAL","ORIGEN_DERECHO", 
                        "NOTAS"};
        modelo = new DefaultTableModel(data, col);//Ejemplo video


        //miTabla1.setModel(model); 

        //miTabla1 = new JTable(informacion,titulos);


        miBarra.setViewportView(miTabla1);
        add(miBarra);
        miBarra.setBounds(27, 72, 379, 130);
    }


private void agregarValores(JSONObject json){   
        int cont = 0;
        //if(modelo==null){
            //miTabla1.setModel(modelo);    
            System.out.println("ttttttttttttttttt");
        //}


        DefaultTableModel modelo= (DefaultTableModel)miTabla1.getModel();   //Aqui marca error  

         Vector row = new Vector();

            //modelo.insertRow(0, new Object[]{});          
            System.out.println("uuuuuuuuuuuuu..."+modelo);  
        //Inserción de valores obtenidos del Json
            JSONObject retencion = (JSONObject)json.get("retencion");
            JSONObject importeNeto = (JSONObject)json.get("importeNeto");
              row.add(json.get("transaccion"));
              row.add(json.get("fechaPago"));
              row.add(json.get("creditoDebito"));
              row.add(retencion.get("percent"));
              row.add(importeNeto.get("amount"));


            /*modelo.setValueAt(json.get("transaccion"), cont, 0);
            modelo.setValueAt(json.get("fechaPago"), cont, 1);

            modelo.setValueAt(json.get("creditoDebito"), cont, 2);
            modelo.setValueAt(retencion.get("percent"), cont, 3);
            modelo.setValueAt(importeNeto.get("amount"), cont, 4);*/

            //modelo.setValueAt("0", cont, 0);
            cont++;     
            //Hasta aca
            miTabla1.setModel(modelo);
    }


private void agregarValores(JSONObject json){   
        int cont = 0;
        //if(modelo==null){
            //miTabla1.setModel(modelo);    
            System.out.println("ttttttttttttttttt");
        //}


        DefaultTableModel modelo= (DefaultTableModel)miTabla1.getModel();   //Aqui marca error  

         Vector row = new Vector();

            //modelo.insertRow(0, new Object[]{});          
            System.out.println("uuuuuuuuuuuuu..."+modelo);  
        //Inserción de valores obtenidos del Json
            JSONObject retencion = (JSONObject)json.get("retencion");
            JSONObject importeNeto = (JSONObject)json.get("importeNeto");
              row.add(json.get("transaccion"));
              row.add(json.get("fechaPago"));
              row.add(json.get("creditoDebito"));
              row.add(retencion.get("percent"));
              row.add(importeNeto.get("amount"));


            /*modelo.setValueAt(json.get("transaccion"), cont, 0);
            modelo.setValueAt(json.get("fechaPago"), cont, 1);

            modelo.setValueAt(json.get("creditoDebito"), cont, 2);
            modelo.setValueAt(retencion.get("percent"), cont, 3);
            modelo.setValueAt(importeNeto.get("amount"), cont, 4);*/

            //modelo.setValueAt("0", cont, 0);
            cont++;     
            //Hasta aca
            miTabla1.setModel(modelo);
    }


private void obtenerMatriz() {//JJ Metodo con el que estoy trabajando

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        try{
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader ("D:/Usuarios/JBustamante/Desktop/C0_2019-05-31_927837_0.json"));

            System.out.println("Cadena completa json del archivo..." + obj);

            JSONObject jsonObjectArchivo = (JSONObject)obj;//se guarda en la variable jsonObject la cadena json del archivo
            Object objJson = jsonObjectArchivo.get("opciones");
            if(objJson instanceof JSONArray){
                System.out.println("Esto es un array de opciones"); 
                JSONArray obj2 =  (JSONArray)objJson;           
                System.out.println("Objsss...."+ obj2);
                //Recorremos en array, ya que sabemos su tamaño  

                for(int i = 0; i< obj2.size();i++){ //Recorrido de transacciones           
                    JSONObject elementoItem =(JSONObject) obj2.get(i);
                    JSONArray transacciones = (JSONArray)(elementoItem.get("transacciones"));
                    for(int j = 0; j< transacciones.size();j++){
                        JSONObject transaccionesItem =(JSONObject)transacciones.get(j);
                        agregarValores(transaccionesItem);
                    }



                }

            }          

        }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

Json:

```
{
  "folioReferencia" : "42667C002",
  "folioEvento" : "92218",
  "tipoMensaje" : "Replace",
  "claveCotizacion" : "ADP",
  "razonSocial" : "AEROPORTS DE PARIS",
  "serie" : "N",
  "isin" : "FR0010340141",
  "mercadoPrincipal" : "EURONEXT PARIS",
  "tipoEvento" : "CashDividend",
  "indicador" : "Mandatory",
  "completo" : "COMPLETE",
  "confirmado" : "CONFIRMED",
  "fechaExdate" : "07\/06\/2019",
  "fechaRegistro" : "10\/06\/2019",
  "tipoEventos" : [ {
    "qualifierDescription" : "Occurrence Type",
    "indicatorDescription" : "FINAL"
  } ],
  "opciones" : [ {
    "numero" : 1,
    "tipo" : "Cash",
    "default" : "true",
    "transacciones" : [ {
      "transaccion" : "Cash Movement",
      "fechaPago" : "11\/06\/2019",
      "creditoDebito" : "Credit",
      "importeBruto" : {
        "amount" : 3.0,
        "currency" : "EUR",
        "rateType" : "TaxablePortion"
      },
      "importeNeto" : {
        "amount" : 2.1,
        "currency" : "EUR",
        "rateType" : "TaxablePortion"
      },
      "retencion" : {
        "percent" : "30.0"
      }
    } ]
  } ],
  "notas" : {
    "addtlTxt" : ""
  }
}
```

Lo desfasado quiero decir que cuando acabo de procesar toda la información me aparece como un cuadro encima de otro, la verdad soy muy nuevo con esta biblioteca de Swing y quería pedirles su ayuda en que puedo estar mal practicamente es la primera que me enfrento a un reto como esto, el codigo no marca error y solo quiero mandar la información a la tabla y que se muestre, posteriormente les dejo como se ve en la interfaz, ya he hecho otros post con este trabajo que estoy realizando, espero y puedan ayudarme por favor se los agradecería bastante, quedo al pendiente de sus comentarios saludos.

Comment: ¿se podrá que nos compartas el json?

Comment: Hola, volví a editar la pregunta y añadí el json, no pude hacerlo en el formato tipo código por que vengo en transporte y no pude hacerlo desde el celular cuando tenga oportunidad lo haré desde la computadora, saludos

Comment: No veo dónde agregas la tabla, pero la recomendación es que la agregues a un JScrollPane: `contenedor.add(new JScrollPane(tabla));`.

Comment: Hola Sal, en que parte de mi codigo agrego contenedor.add(new JScrollPane(tabla));? Saludos

Comment: Ya edité mi pregunta y puse como tengo declarado JScrollPane

Answer (score 1):

Ya que estás creando vectores a partir del JSON, puedes agregar los datos al modelo con: `modelo.insertRow(0, row);`, pero hazlo después de setear los valores del JSON; considera que normalmente en las implementaciones MVC la vista se actualiza cuando hay cambios en el modelo, pero si insertas un renglón con `new Object[]{}` la tabla se actualizará con datos vacíos.

Por otro lado, normalmente después de hacer algún cambio directamente al modelo no es necesario volver a setear el modelo como en la última línea de `setearValores`.